# When creating a Cloud Data Loss Prevention (DLP) job where is the metadata later found?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dlp

[Python create_dlp_job method](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/dlp/latest/google.cloud.dlp_v2.services.dlp_service.DlpServiceClient#google_cloud_dlp_v2_services_dlp_service_DlpServiceClient_create_dlp_job)

I want to associate some additional data with a DLP job.

The create_dlp_job method has a metadata parameter. Is there a method that allows me to retrieve that metadata from the dlp job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only job types that support additional information are Hybrid inspect jobs.  https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/dlp/latest/google.cloud.dlp_v2.types.HybridOptions